# Importing pg_featureserv services into ArcGIS Pro as WFS layer

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, wfs

I'm currently working with pg_featureserv. I have successfully added the layer to QGIS using [this tutorial](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/using-postgis-and-pg_featureserv-with-qgis). I have not, however, been able to add the service to ArcGIS as a WFS layer.

Has anyone had any success doing this?

I'm unable to find any documentation on it.

I'm using the same machine and same URL as specified in the tutorial (http://*IP Address*:9000/ when going to insert > project > connections > WFS server in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Following your link it says pg_featureserv serves the data using the OGC API for Features and the not the 'old' WFS protocol. ArcGIS Pro (2.8) apparently can use these services with another method listed here:https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/services/add-ogc-api-services.htm

Comment: Great to see pg_featureserv being used.  Let us know if you find any issues when connecting it to ArcGIS (by posting an issue on the Github repo:  https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_featureserv